# ASP.NET Server Side ProgressBar

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

I am currently working on an online quiz component and need to add a progress bar to the page for users to see their total progress through the quiz (eg. if they have done 2/50 questions the bar will be at 4%). Something that looks similar to [this](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2009/03/30/display-progress-bar-column-in-asp-net-grid.aspx) except as a standalone progressbar and not a column in a gridview.

Without writing one from scratch does anyone know of any existing components or samples that exist for this?

Please note that since it is not for a client side or asynchronous process I am NOT looking for one that uses AJAX/JQuery/Javascript (they seem to be all I find when searching!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This describes a fairly easy way to do this with a little bit of html and css: [Shiny Progress Bar Technique](http://blog.benogle.com/2009/06/16/simple-css-shiny-progress-bar-technique/)

Comment: Perfect, nice and simple exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Link dead. This is why you don't just link answers. -1

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Ajax to use the JQuery UI Progress bar.

It looks quite nice too:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

If you use it and it looks odd, you'll need to ensure you're including the JQuery UI CSS files.

Comment: Nice, but as i said in my question looking for one without JQuery :)